# Docker compose build error - Project file does not exist

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to create docker compose which run my ASP.NET Core app and mssql, but I'm getting an error during build.

Here's my docker compose file:

```
# Build Stage
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:latest as build-env
WORKDIR /source
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore ./Travelingowe.sln
RUN dotnet publish --output ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} --configuration Release

# Publish Stage
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:latest
COPY --from=build-env ./obj/Docker/publish /app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]
```

when I run in CMD -> **docker-compose up** I'm getting:

```
Building api
Step 1/9 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:latest as build-env
 ---> d6273f7c44d4
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /source
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 978f1c31e14a
Step 3/9 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bcc750adcb99
Step 4/9 : RUN dotnet restore ./Travelingowe.sln
 ---> Running in 764199859de4
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: ./Travelingowe.sln
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore ./Travelingowe.sln' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Do you have any ide what is wrong?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
My project files:
[image]

Comment: You changed your working directory to "/source". Is that where Travelingowe.sln is? If not, you could change your working directory back, or use a relative path from /source

Comment: @pixelbits I updated my post with a screenshot of my project files.

Answer (score 0):

you have issues with your working directory try using absolute path instead of relative path in your working directory in docker file

Comment: Dockerfile is inside Api folder. Also I tan docker-compose up from the screenshot folder location.

Comment: But it seems like docker doesn't;t see solution file.

Comment: Try using dotnet restore without providing the solution file name

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

Put your `Dockerfile` in your project root folder.

---

There are several question you need to think of:

- Where is your `Dockerfile`?
- How does `docker-compose.yaml` point to `Dockerfile`?

It seems like you put your `Dockerfile` in the other folder.

As [document](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#dockerfile) mentions:

> Compose uses an alternate file to build with. A build path must also be specified.

When you use the `Dockerfile` on different folder with `docker-compose.yaml` you have to set up the `context` property.

As it set up, it will consider the `Dockerfile`'s folder as project root folder. So when the command `dotnet restore ./Travelingowe.sln` executed, it shows you the error

You can manually test the command by running `dotnet restore ./Travelingowe.sln` in `Dockerfile`'s folder. It should show the detail error message.